# Develop alarm skill with Alexa Device except voice input

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am new to Amazon Alexa having one query about AVS & Alexa device,

How to enable Alexa to be enable to speak without voice input? Is this possible to give input by any other way except voice and take output from Alexa device in voice format?

Comment: you can't run jobs or self-invocating skill on Alexa, there always need to be a **Invocation**  for alexa to respond. Only In-Built functionality have access to these features like reminders and alarms.

Answer (score 0):

Alexa is the device completely designed for voice interaction and it will always expect a voice input to respond.